# The package to visualize graphs

Tags: graphics, graphs

What could be the packages to use for visualization of graphs?
I tried Graphviz, but it's very hard to direct how the graphs should be shown.

How can I make the graphs represented as is shown in the examples (excerpt from [Graph Theory and Complex Networks: An Introduction](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9081540610)).

[image: enter imagGraph Theory and Complex Networks: An Introductione description here]
[image]
[image]

Comment: TikZ, PSTricks, Asymptote. See [Numbering nodes in a for loop](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/132982), [How can I label TikZ-graphs on four vertices with a loop?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/131426) and http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/complete-graph/. — What do you struggle with? What have your tried? TikZ can do this with `\foreach` loops and `chains` and stuff. — Do you have a specific input syntax?

Comment: if you use LuaTeX and watn to to graph layout in an automatic way, you might want to take a look at Jannis work (diploma thesis) http://gezeiten.org/tag/tikz

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel -- It's funny, all three famous packages are shown in three answers. Generally the choice depends on users.

Comment: @selwyndd21 No surprise there. That’s why I linked the related topics. We already have examples (especially for TikZ) on how to *draw* such graphics. I’m still interested in how OP wants to *create* these diagrams (“input syntax”). There is also TikZ’ new Lua Graphdrawing library which could be very helpful (see Ronny’s comment).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use TikZ.  Here's a very minimal example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={circle,inner sep=2pt,fill=black}]
  \node (A) at (0,0) {};
  \node (B) at (1,1) {};
  \node (C) at (0,1) {};
  \node (D) at (1,0) {};

  \draw (A) -- (B)
        (A) -- (C)
        (A) -- (D)
        (B) -- (D);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can use `pstricks`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-node}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](1,1)
\pnode(0,0){A}
\pnode(1,1){B}    
\pnode(0,1){C}    
\pnode(1,0){D}    

\rput(A){\psdot}
\rput(B){\psdot}
\rput(C){\psdot}
\rput(D){\psdot}

\psline(A)(B)
\psline(A)(C)
\psline(A)(D)
\psline(B)(D)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

While this following example could be done a bit more efficiently, it does show that you can make very nicely connected graphs:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\mycircleofnodes{C0}
  \foreach \x in {0,30,...,330}
    {
      \node[circle,fill=black,inner sep=2pt] (C\x) at (\x:3) {} ;
      \ifnum\x>0\relax\xdef\mycircleofnodes{\mycircleofnodes,C\x}\fi
    }
  \foreach \x in {0,30,...,330}
    {
      \foreach \y in \mycircleofnodes
        {
          \draw (\y) -- (C\x);
        }
    }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you don't want to connect every node to each other, then you can do something along the following lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\mycircleofnodes{C0}
  \foreach \x in {0,1,...,11}
    {
      \node[circle,fill=black,inner sep=2pt] (C\x) at (\x*30:3) {} ;
      \ifnum\x>0\relax\xdef\mycircleofnodes{\mycircleofnodes,C\x}\fi
    }

  \foreach \x/\y in {0/1,0/2,0/3,0/4,0/5,0/6,0/7,%
                     2/4,%
                     5/6,5/7,5/10,%
                     8/9,8/11}
    {
      \draw (C\x) -- (C\y);
    }

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's (only) the beginning of how to set up something like your second example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pagestyle{empty}

\def\rowA{0}
\def\rowB{0,1,...,9}
\def\rowC{0,1,...,17}
\def\rowD{0,1,...,13}
\def\rowE{0,1,...,5}
\def\rowF{0}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.5cm,
                    y=1.75cm,
                    every node/.style={circle,
                                       inner sep=2pt,
                                       fill=black}
                   ]

  \foreach \x in \rowA { \node (A\x) at (\x-0.5,2)  {}; }
  \foreach \x in \rowB { \node (B\x) at (\x-5,1)    {}; }
  \foreach \x in \rowC { \node (C\x) at (\x-9,0)    {}; }
  \foreach \x in \rowD { \node (D\x) at (\x-7,-1)   {}; }
  \foreach \x in \rowE { \node (E\x) at (\x-3,-2)   {}; }
  \foreach \x in \rowF { \node (F\x) at (\x-0.5,-3) {}; }

  \foreach \x    in {4,8,9}                    { \draw (A0)  -- (B\x); }
  \foreach \x/\y in {0/2,1/7,1/8,1/17}         { \draw (B\x) -- (C\y); }

  \foreach \x/\y in {0/0,0/7,0/8,0/10,1/4,1/8} { \draw (E\x) -- (D\y); }
  \foreach \x/\y in {0/0,0/1,0/2,0/3,0/4,0/5}  { \draw (F\x) -- (E\y); }

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Be advised!  Both `pstricks` and `tikz` have their own learning curves.  They both have ample documentation.  The documentation for `pstricks` is spread over multiple `pdf` files, which at times can lead to frustration when you don't know where to look for the documentation.  `tikz` has an immense and very comprehensive manual (though knowing which libraries are necessary can be a bit frustrating at times).

Answer (score 11):

[image]
[image]

`Asymptote` provides a lot of convenient programming means to handle data structures.
Here is one way to draw circular visualisation of graphs:

```
% visg.tex :
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inline]{asymptote}
\begin{asydef}
struct circGraph{    
  real r;
  string[] links;
  int n;

  pair node(int i){
    return rotate(90+i*360/n)*(r,0);
  }

  real lineW;
  pen linePen;
  pen[] linePens;

  pen nodePenO=invisible+3*linewidth(linePen);
  pen nodePenA=white;
  pen nodePenB=orange;

  real labelOff;

  void drawLines(){
    int lineCount;
    for(int i=0;i<links.length;++i){
      lineCount=0;
      for(int j=0;j<n;++j){
        if(substr(links[i],j,1)=="1"){
          draw(node(i)--node(j),linePens[lineCount]);
          ++lineCount;
        };
      }
    }
  }

  void drawNodes(){
    for(int i=0;i<n;++i){
      pair p=node(i);
      dot(p,nodePenO,RadialShade(nodePenA,nodePenB));
      label(string(i),labelOff*p);
    }
  }

  void operator init(
    string[] links
    ,real r=1
    ,pen[] linePens={lightred,darkgreen,blue}
    ,real lineW=0.6bp
    ,pen nodePenA=white
    ,pen nodePenB=orange
    ,real labelOff=1.08
  ){
    this.links    = links;
    this.r        = r;
    this.linePens = copy(linePens);
    this.lineW    = lineW;
    this.nodePenA = nodePenA;
    this.nodePenB = nodePenB;
    this.nodePenO=invisible+3*lineW;
    this.labelOff=labelOff;

    this.n=length(links[0]);
    this.linePens.cyclic=true;
    drawLines();
    drawNodes();
  }
}
\end{asydef}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{asy}
size(300);
defaultpen(fontsize(10pt));

string[] links={
"00000000000000000001100000000011100000000000000000",
"00000000000000000010000010000001101000000000000000",
"00000000000010100100000101100000001000000000000000",
"00000000000001010000100000000000000000000000000000",
"00000000000010000010000001100000000000000000000000",
"00000000000010000000000100000010100000000000000000",
"00000000000001000100000010100000000000000000000000",
"00000000000000001001000000000100001000000000000000",
"00000000000000000000110001100100000110000000000000",
"00000000000001101000100011010000000000000000000000",
"00000000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000",
"00000000000000000000000000000001000000000000000000",
"00000000000000000000000000000000000000100010100000",
"00000000000000000000000000000000000000000001001000",
"00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"00000000000000000000000000000000000000010100010000",
"00000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000000",
"00000000000000000000000000000000000000010000100010",
"00000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000",
"00000000000000000000000000000000000001000100000010",
"00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100",
"00000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000",
"00000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000",
"00000000000000000000000000000000000000000100010000",
"00000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000000",
"00000000000000000000000000000000000000100000001000",
"00000000000000000000000000000000000000011010000100",
"00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001",
"00000000000000000000000000000000000000100001000000",
"00000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000001",
"00000000000000000000000000000000000000100001000000",
"00000000000000000000000000000000000000100000001000",
"00000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000000",
"00000000000000000000000000000000000001010000000010",
"00000000000000000000000000000000000000001000011000",
"00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
"00000000000000000000000000000000000001000000000010",
"00000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000",
"00000000000000000000000000000000000000010000000000",
};

circGraph(links); 
shipout(bbox(Fill(paleyellow)));

\end{asy}
\end{figure}
%
\begin{figure}
\begin{asy}
size(200);
defaultpen(fontsize(10pt));

string[] links={
"00000000110000000001110000",
"00000001000001000000110100",
"01010010000010110000000100",
"00101000010000000000000000",
"01000001000000110000000000",
"01000000000010000001010000",
"00100010000001010000000000",
"00000100100000000010000100",
"00000000011000110010000011",
"00110100010001101000000000",
"00000000000000000000000100",
};

currentpen=olive;
circGraph(links,linePens=new pen[]{black,white}
  ,nodePenA=yellow
  ,nodePenB=brown  
  ,labelOff=1.2); 
shipout(bbox(Fill(paleblue)));

\end{asy}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
%
% Process:
% pdflatex visg.tex    
% asy asy visg-*.asy
% pdflatex visg.tex
```

Comment: Asymptote and g.kov both rock! +1

Comment: An off-topic question: Is it easy to find the intersection points of two arbitrary curves in Aysmptote? For example, curves passing through `(1,2)(2,4)(4,-1)...` and `(0,-2)(2,3)(4,3)...`, respectively.

Comment: @PGFTricks:

`size(300);
guide p=(1,2)..(2,4)..(4,-1);
guide q=(0,-2)..(2,3)..(4,3);
draw(p,red);
draw(q,green);
dot(intersectionpoint(p,q),UnFill);`

Comment: @PGFTricks:
You might also find it useful to use functions `real[][] intersections`,
`pair[] intersectionpoints` and `path subpath` (among the others),
see `asymptote.pdf`.

Answer (score 10):

Just for fun with PSTricks.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node,pst-plot}

\psset{showpoints}

\def\Graph#1{%
\begin{pspicture}(-2,-2)(2,2)
    \curvepnodes[plotpoints=\numexpr#1+1]{0}{360}{2 t PtoC}{P}
    \multido{\ix=0+1,\itemp=1+1}{\Pnodecount}{%
        \multido{\iy=\itemp+1}{\numexpr\Pnodecount-1-\ix}{\psline(P\ix)(P\iy)}}
\end{pspicture}}

\begin{document}
    \multido{\i=3+1}{10}{\Graph{\i}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Remarks:

`Pnodecount` is the last index that is equal to `plotpoints` minus 1. As the first point and the last point are on the same radial line in the case of a full circular domain, the last point must be excluded. Be careful with [off-by-one error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error) when specifying the loop range.

The key `plotpoints` is defined in `pst-plot` and the macro `\curvepnodes` is defined in `pst-node`. When we use `\curvepnodes` with `plotpoints`, we have to load both packages. If you forget to load `pst-plot` (as I did often), the `\curvepnodes[plotpoints=...]...` will not compile. I don't know whether it should be regarded a bad design pattern applied to packages with cross-linking.

Answer (score 9):

I answered a different question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120236/drawing-bipartite-graph/120248#120248) but most of the answer is relevant to your question. You want to use `tikz` in combination with the `tkz-graph`, and `tkz-berge` packages. The beautiful results are in the PDF ["Gallery of Named Graphs"](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CDUQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.altermundus.fr%2Fdownloads%2Fdocuments%2FNamedGraphs.pdf&ei=XzPDUZz6DJDO9gS9_oHoAw&usg=AFQjCNGvwk0ezzts7Vc2JaNRPVcJgykJHA&bvm=bv.48175248,d.eWU); they are comparable with the examples you have given. The graph packages are due to Alain Matthes of the [Altermundus site](http://altermundus.com/index.html). The computer algebra system [Sage supports tikz and Altermundus' packages as well as LaTeX](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/graphs/sage/graphs/graph_latex.html?highlight=graph%20tikz).