# TikZ chain adjust positions of on-the-arrow node

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, nodes, arrows

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain=circle placed {at=(\tikzchaincount*30:1.5)},regular/.style={draw,circle,inner sep=0,minimum size=4mm}]
\foreach \i in {0,...,11}
  \node [on chain, regular] (\i) {\i};
\foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \ni using {int(mod(\i+1,12))}] \i in {0,3,6,9}
  {\draw [->] (\i) to [bend right] node[auto] {$p_b$} (\ni); }
\foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \ni using {int(Mod(\i-1,12))}] \i in {0,3,6,9}
  {\draw [->] (\i) to [bend right] node[auto] {$q_b$} (\ni); }
\foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \ni using {int(mod(\i+1,12))}] \i in {1,2,4,5,7,8,10,11}
  {\draw [->] (\i) to [bend right] node[auto] {$p_g$} (\ni); }
\foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \ni using {int(Mod(\i-1,12))}] \i in {1,2,4,5,7,8,10,11}
  {\draw [->] (\i) to [bend right] node[auto] {$q_g$} (\ni); }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

gave me

[image]

Although I have used `node[auto]` and there is certainly enough room to layout all the on-the-arrow node labels, they still crowd into a mess. I am aware that I have the option of using `node[auto,above]` or `node[auto,below]` to fine-tune the position, but that would make the code lengthy. Is there a simple way to lay out those labels beautifully?

Comment: The nodes are placed on inner side. You need to `swap` them or use `auto=right`. The problem with `auto` is that it snaps to the main anchors (multiples of 45). You will need a more sophisticated node setup for such small distances.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quite similar to the other answers, but with one or two less keystrokes.

```
\documentclass[border=0.125cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{topaths}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach \n in {0,...,11}
    \node [draw, circle] at (\n*30+30:2.5) (n-\n) {\n};

\foreach \n [evaluate={\m=int(mod(11+\n, 12)); \p=int(mod(\n+1,3)); \q=int(mod(\n,3)); }] in {0,...,11}{
    \draw [->] (n-\m) to [bend right] node [anchor=\n*30+210] {$P_\ifodd\p b\else g\fi$} (n-\n);
    \draw [<-] (n-\m) to [bend left]  node [anchor=\n*30+30]  {$P_\ifodd\q b\else g\fi$} (n-\n);
}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Really nice code!

Answer (score 7):

With PSTricks just for fun as usual!

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node,pst-plot}

\makeatletter
% Get Label
\def\GL#1#2{\pst@mod{#2}{3}\rem\ifcase\rem $#1_b$ \or $#1_g$ \or $#1_g$\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[radius=12pt,arcangle=30,arrows=<-](-3,-3)(3,3)
    \curvepnodes[plotpoints=13]{0}{360}{2.5 t 30 add PtoC}{P}
    \multido{\i=0+1}{\Pnodecount}{\Cnodeput(P\i){A\i}{\i}}
    \Cnodeput(P\Pnodecount){A\Pnodecount}{}
    \multido{\ix=0+1,\iy=1+1}{\Pnodecount}
    {
        \ncarc{A\iy}{A\ix}\naput{\GL{p}{\ix}}
        \ncarc{A\ix}{A\iy}\naput{\GL{q}{\iy}}
    }
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Just another option

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node,pst-plot}

\makeatletter
% Get Label
\def\GL#1#2{\pst@mod{#2}{3}\rem\ifcase\rem $#1_b$ \or $#1_g$ \or $#1_g$\fi}
% Angle unit operator
\def\angleunit#1{\degrees[#1]\pstVerb{/angleunit {\pst@angleunit} bind def}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[radius=12pt,arcangle=30,arrows=<-](-3,-3)(3,3)
    \angleunit{12}
    \curvepnodes[plotpoints=13]{0}{12}{2.5 t 1 add angleunit PtoC}{P}
    \multido{\i=0+1}{\Pnodecount}{\Cnodeput(P\i){A\i}{\i}}
    \Cnodeput(P\Pnodecount){A\Pnodecount}{}
    \multido{\ix=0+1,\iy=1+1}{\Pnodecount}
    {
        \ncarc{A\iy}{A\ix}\naput{\GL{p}{\ix}}
        \ncarc{A\ix}{A\iy}\naput{\GL{q}{\iy}}
    }
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

The difference is

```
\angleunit{12}
\curvepnodes[plotpoints=13]{0}{12}{2.5 t 1 add angleunit PtoC}{P}
```

where

```
\makeatletter
\def\angleunit#1{\degrees[#1]\pstVerb{/angleunit {\pst@angleunit} bind def}}
\makeatother
```

is defined in the preamble.

### The simplest one

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node,pst-plot}

\makeatletter
% Get Label
\def\GL#1#2{\pst@mod{#2}{3}\rem\ifodd\rem $#1_b$ \else $#1_g$ \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[radius=12pt,arcangle=30,arrows=<-](-3,-3)(3,3)
    \multido{\i=0+1}{12}{\Cnodeput(!2.5 \i\space 1 add 30 mul PtoC){A\i}{\i}}
    \Cnodeput(A0){A12}{}% auxiliary node
    \multido{\ix=0+1,\iy=1+1}{12}
    {
        \ncarc{A\iy}{A\ix}\naput{\GL{p}{\iy}}
        \ncarc{A\ix}{A\iy}\naput{\GL{q}{\numexpr\ix+2}}
    }
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

No more significant edit in the future!

Comment: Elegant and short! The only thing is that I think it should be `plotpoints=13` to get all the circle with numbers.

Comment: check the labels...

Comment: @percusse In the question I see labels `0` to `11` so `12` would seem okay, but the output 'only' shows `0` to `10`. (Am I missing something obvious?) [I assumed this was a note for me; am I right?]

Comment: @SvendTveskæg there is no alphabetical progression but a pattern modulo three

Answer (score 7):

Two problems:

1. The `auto` option places the nodes by default to the `left`, you will need to use `auto=right` (or the `swap` option which swaps the default side).
2. The `auto` option snaps to the main compass anchors `east`, `north east`, `north`, …, `south` and `south east`.

You want to use `circle` nodes so that anchors are placed in a circle around the node.
You want to use `text depth=+0pt` or similar solution to hide the different depths of the subscripts.
And you want to use another `auto` anchor/angle calculator. This is what this answer has to offer.

By the way, you might be interested in the [`nodes around center`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/131491/16595) key for the placement of nodes in a chain. One might also add the edge nodes via the `join` style but that’s for another question.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\pgfmathparse{atan2(0,1)}% the CVS version swaps the arguments so I define new atan
                         % functions that have the order of arguments in their name
\ifdim\pgfmathresult pt=0pt % atan2(y, x)
  \tikzset{declare function={atanXY(\x,\y)=atan2(\y,\x);atanYX(\y,\x)=atan2(\y,\x);}}
\else                       % atan2(x, y)
  \tikzset{declare function={atanXY(\x,\y)=atan2(\x,\y);atanYX(\y,\x)=atan2(\x,\y);}}
\fi
\makeatletter
\let\tikz@auto@anchor@orig      \tikz@auto@anchor
\let\tikz@auto@anchor@prime@orig\tikz@auto@anchor@prime
\tikzset{
  Auto/.code=\pgfkeysalso{/tikz/auto=#1}%
    \let\tikz@auto@anchor      \tikz@Auto@anchor
    \let\tikz@auto@anchor@prime\tikz@Auto@anchor@prime,
  auto/.prefix code=\let\tikz@auto@anchor      \tikz@Auto@anchor@orig
                    \let\tikz@auto@anchor@prime\tikz@Auto@anchor@prime@orig}
\def\tikz@Auto@anchor{%
  \pgfmathatanXY@{\pgf@sys@tonumber\pgf@x}{\pgf@sys@tonumber\pgf@y}%
  \pgfutil@tempdima=\pgfmathresult pt\relax
  \advance\pgfutil@tempdima-90pt\relax
  \edef\tikz@anchor{\pgf@sys@tonumber\pgfutil@tempdima}}
\def\tikz@Auto@anchor@prime{%
  \pgfmathatanXY@{\pgf@sys@tonumber\pgf@x}{\pgf@sys@tonumber\pgf@y}%
  \pgfutil@tempdima=\pgfmathresult pt\relax
  \advance\pgfutil@tempdima90pt\relax
  \edef\tikz@anchor{\pgf@sys@tonumber\pgfutil@tempdima}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[Auto=right,
  start chain=circle placed {at=(\tikzchaincount*30:1.5)},
  regular/.style={draw,circle,inner sep=+0pt,minimum size=+4mm}]
\foreach \i in {0,...,11} \node [on chain, regular] (\i) {\i};
\tikzset{text depth=+0pt, shape=circle, inner sep=+2pt}
\foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \ni using {int(mod(\i+1,12))}] \i in {0,3,6,9}
  {\draw [->] (\i) to [bend right] node {$p_b$} (\ni); }
\foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \ni using {int(Mod(\i-1,12))}] \i in {0,3,6,9}
  {\draw [->] (\i) to [bend right] node {$q_b$} (\ni); }
\foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \ni using {int(mod(\i+1,12))}] \i in {1,2,4,5,7,8,10,11}
  {\draw [->] (\i) to [bend right] node {$p_g$} (\ni); }
\foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \ni using {int(Mod(\i-1,12))}] \i in {1,2,4,5,7,8,10,11}
  {\draw [->] (\i) to [bend right] node {$q_g$} (\ni); }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Some coordinate calculations are also useful.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain=circle placed {at=(\tikzchaincount*30:1.5)},
                    regular/.style={draw,circle,inner sep=0,minimum size=4mm}]
\foreach \i in {0,...,11}
\node [on chain, regular] (\i) {\i};
\foreach \i [evaluate=\i as \ni using {int(mod(\i+1,12))},
           evaluate=\i as \pi using {int(Mod(\i-1,12))}] \i in {0,...,11}
{
\draw [->] (\i) to [bend right] (\ni);
\draw [->] (\i) to [bend right] (\pi); 
\node[] at ($($(\i)!0.5!(\pi)$)!1!90:(\pi)$) {\pgfmathparse{Mod(\i,3)==0?"$q_b$":"$p_g$"}\pgfmathresult};
\node[] at ($($(\i)!0.5!(\ni)$)!1!90:(\ni)$) {\pgfmathparse{Mod(\i,3)==0?"$p_b$":"$q_g$"}\pgfmathresult};
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]